# Creating a Vertical menu using jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, menu

How can I create a page like this?

[image]

When I click a link in the left side menu a page must be loaded in the content area, but the whole page must not load.

How to do this using jquery is there any plugin to do that?

Comment: Can you create the vertical menu? What have you tried that isn't working? To load into just the content area use ajax to get the html and just put it into the content area element using innerHTML.

Answer (score 0):

i thing you need to load everything on page and selected content [who you want to show] is show by using jquery.show() and all other content [unselect] is hide using jqury.hide();

if you use link as hyperlink you must need first to disable him using [preventdefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) or you need to make a event on div click.